# How to add timestamp of inserting a document from external source in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, spray-json

I am new to mongo db, I am trying to insert a vector of documents into MongoDb from an external source(cloud database). I want to add the timestamp of when the document is loaded in mongodb along with the document I am inserting. I don't want to update the document later with adding a time field. How do I do this?
For example:
Below is the json format of the document I am getting from cloud

```
{_id:123
cloudtimestamp:"20201212T5:00:00.000+00.00"
data:{
val1:2
val2:3
}
//TO-DO add insertTimestamp
```

}

Before I insert the above document into mongodb, I want to add the insertion timestamp in the place of //TO-DO comment

Comment: You may want to leave the _id to its default behaviour of populating with an ObjectId. The [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#mongodb-method-ObjectId) that is generated automatically will contains timestamp info, which you can fetch by using [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)

Comment: Thank you. That would mean I will be updating the documents after insertion with the timestamp. What I am looking at is to insert the document with the insertion timestamp along with  the other data it has. I will keep the _id as the ObjectId generated by mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve OP's situation is to keep the default behaviour of populating with an ObjectId and only maintain a modified_at timestamp.

According to the [official MongoDB documentation of ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#mongodb-method-ObjectId),

> The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:
>
> a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId's creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch

Thus the insertion/creation time can be fetched by using [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/).